# JabRef comments @PREAMBLE entry

Tags: bibtex, jabref

When I open `.bib` files that have a `@PREAMBLE` entry, JabRef comments this entry after saving and refuses to open the file the next time. How can I prevent this from happening?

`.bib` file before using JabRef:

```
@PREAMBLE{{\providecommand{\noopsort}[1]{}}}

@Article{AF,
  author =        {M. Anderson and T. Feil},
  title =         {{Turning Lights Out with Linear Algebra}},
  journal =       {Mathematics Magazine},
  year =          {1998},
  volume =        {71},
  number =        {4},
  pages =         {300 -- 303},
}
```

`.bib` file after opening in JabRef:

```
% Encoding: UTF-8@PREAMBLE{{\providecommand{\noopsort}[1]{}}}

@Article{AF,
  author =        {M. Anderson and T. Feil},
  title =         {{Turning Lights Out with Linear Algebra}},
  journal =       {Mathematics Magazine},
  year =          {1998},
  volume =        {71},
  number =        {4},
  pages =         {300 -- 303},
}
```

Comment: Are you using an up-to-date JabRef? It apparently was an issue in [v. 3.2](https://github.com/JabRef/jabref/issues/669) but should have been [fixed meanwhile](https://github.com/JabRef/jabref/pull/718).

Comment: I would recommend to test with the version available at https://builds.jabref.org/master/. It is the latest development version. If it is not fixed there, file an issue on GitHub. Otherwise, donate the developers some time of yours so that they have time to work on finishing the release. See https://help.jabref.org/en/FAQcontributing for ideas how to contribute.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because solved by updating